# How to migrate swagger 2.0 schemes field into openApi?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

In our old swagger 2.0 definitions, we have the following line:

```
  "schemes" : [ "http", "https" ]
```

When deployed, we can see in swagger UI a select box that allows us to choose a scheme, which is quite useful when running locally.

Now, I'd like to convert our API to OpenApi. I tried doing so using the Swagger editor at https://swagger.io/ which has an automatic conversion tool, but the scheme line had disappeared. Is it deprecated in OpenApi? I couldn't find any guide on what to use instead. Any ideas what I should do to allow local developers to choose which scheme to use even using OpenApi definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`servers` replaces the `host`, `basePath` and `schemes` keywords used in OpenAPI 2.0**

In this case, you'd want to define two servers (http and https).

```
servers:
  - url: http://api.example.com/v1
  - url: https://api.example.com/v1
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/).

Comment: Thanks, but what was good about the old definition was that you didn't need to specify the url, which differs in different environments, only the protocol. So is there like a magical variable one could use instead?

Comment: You'll have to define multiple servers for each environment, or otherwise alter your toolchain.